# Smarty - How to ask for a DOM element

Tags: php, smarty

I have a tpl that is included from other tpls (actually almost 70). The problem is that this template must do something if it's been included inside a given DOM element (as first child).

Here's is an example:

```
<div id="container">
    {include file="mytpl.tpl"
    param1="aValue1"
    param2="aValue2"
    }
</div>
```

Using Javascript is out of the question, because this affects the backend.

Also, I know I can pass an additional argument to my tpl. The problem is that I'd have to add that instruction to all the almost 70 files that call that tpl.

So, what I'd like to be able to do is to ask if its parent is "container" and it is its first child.

One file solution:

```
{include file="mytpl.tpl"
    param1="aValue1"
    param2="aValue2"
    paramX="X"
}
```

and then, in the tpl..

```
{if $paramX eq 'X'}...{/if}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do if the parent is container and the current template is the first child? You say yow know how you could do but the problem that you have 70 files... ...can you give an example how you would do with one file?

Comment: include file="mytpl.tpl"
    param1="aValue1"
    param2="aValue2
    paramX="X"

and then..

{if $paramX eq 'X'}...{/if}

Comment: @ORION - That's what's your code is. But what do you want to achieve? I mean, what should happen when it is the first child?

Comment: Ok, the situation is more complex. We have 2 apps, A (php) and B (java). A is generating a .jsp file (java code) for B. A has several tpls that include the same tpl, but in different positions. This tpl contains some java code and, depending on the position it's being included in the DOM, will also contain a particular flag.

Comment: @ORION, aha ok. Then I understand your issue. Another question: What does this particular flag tell you? (what is it for)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld Well, this flag tells the Java Tag Engine we developed to do something specific for that element.

Comment: @ORION - Would it be possible to check where in the dom the tpl is included from the java-code using http://jsoup.org/ ?

Comment: Nope, because the Tag engine processes one tag at a time, thus, it's not aware of the position of the tag in the DOM tree. I gave up and started writing a Python script to take care of the replacement. Thanks @bestprogrammerintheworld

Comment: @ORION, ok - sorry I couldn't help you - it seemed you helped yourself though :-)

Comment: np :) I'm not a PHP developer. I'm just trying to help a team mate to meet our sprint deadline. Since these templates are not changed frequently, I guess that the script will do just fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach:
You can put your `variable/data/info` in a `$_SESSION` array and then use:

```
{$smarty.session.YOUR_VARIABLE}
```

Comment: Thanks! But, for doing so I'd have to add that manually in all the 70 files, right? I mean, I'd have to set that variable for all those files.